# Can there be an AngularJS directive to manage an array of conditions?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm new to AngularJS and my project at the moment has a menu that only needs to be displayed sometimes.

I therefore have:

```
<div class="iframe-hide" 
     ng-show="$state.includes('deposit.card.start')||
              $state.includes('deposit.card.3ds')||
              $state.includes('deposit.card.waiting')||
              $state.includes('deposit.bank')||
              $state.includes('deposit.x')||
              $state.is('deposit.x.start')||
              $state.is('deposit.y.start')||
              $state.is('deposit.y.frame')">
```

As you can imagine, as the project grows this becomes unmanageable, so I want to look into tidying it up and creating perhaps a custom directive that will handle these conditions better.

I've been thinking of adding a custom data parameter like this:

```
            .state("deposit.card.waiting", {
                url: "/waiting",
                templateUrl: "app/deposit/templates/card/waiting.html",
                data: { includeMenu: true }
            })
```

The Html instead would be:

```
<div class="iframe-hide" show-if-true="includeMenu">
```

And then a directive that will check whether includeMenu is true. I wrote it here:

```
export class showIfTrueDirective {

    static $inject = ["$", "$rootScope"];
    static $rootScope: any;

    public static build($, $rootScope) {
        var directive: ng.IDirective = {
            link: (scope, element, attributes: any) => {
                var itemToShow = attributes["showIfTrue"]; 
                // this correctly prints "includeMenu"

                // grab the data from current state?. If includeMenu == true then show element, otherwise hide element 
            }
        };
        return directive;
    }
}
```

if I hook that up:

```
.directive("showIfTrue", ["$", "$rootScope", (r, s) => { return ShowIfTrueDirective.build(r,s); }])
```

If I manage to grab the scope data then this might work but this is my first week using Anglular and not entirely sure what I'm doing. Is there a better solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it:

```
export class NgHideDirective {
    static $inject = ["$rootScope"];
    static $rootScope: any;

    public static build($rootScope) {
        var directive: ng.IDirective = {
            link: (scope, element, attributes: any) => {

                var itemToHide = attributes["ngHide"]; 

                $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
                    (event, toState) => {
                        if (toState.data.hasOwnProperty(itemToHide)) {
                            element.hide();
                        } else {
                            element.show();
                        }
                    });
            }
        };
        return directive;
    }
}
```

So if we now do this on an element:

```
<div class="iframe" ng-hide="hideMenu">
```

And this on the state:

```
.state("deposit.x.rejected", {
url: "/rejected",
templateUrl: "app/deposit/templates/x/rejected.html",
data: { hideDepositMenu: null }
```

Then the div will be hidden.

However this doesn't work when page is refreshed for some reason.